# Как сделать вывод, как в VK

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Помогите сделать вывод сообщений как в диалоговом окне в VK( не по стилю, а по функционалу),что бы выводило сообщения по времени(вместо его я использую id, это правильно?Его вроде так же можно проверить, какое сообщения надо высветить первым, а какое последним).С использованием RedBean.php( Кто о нем не слышал, я все прокоментировал).
Вот примерный код:

```
<?php
    $user = R::FindOne('foxland',' login = ?',array($_POST['from']));// Беру из БД юзера который отправил сообщение, т.е. $user хранит все значение из какой-либо строки, к примеру имя или пароль.
    $show = R::Find('message',' `from` = ? ',array($user->login)); // Беру сообщение который отправили допустим, мне.
    $show2 = R::Find('message',' `to` = ? ',array($user->login));// Беру сообщение который отправил допустим, Я.
?>
```

2 дня уже копаюсь не могу найти ответ как только не пробовал.
Вот БД:

```
foxland:
- id
- login
- password
message:
- id
- from // от кого
- to // кому
- text // Текст сообщения
```

PS.
В програмировании я недано, начел серьезно заниматься где-то 2 месяца назад, так что жду советов от профи:)
Эти переменный ассоциативные, многомерный и динамические массивы.
Вот что содержит допустим $show, лично для меня это все каша:

```
Array ( 
  [1] => RedBeanPHP\OODBBean Object ( 
    [properties:protected] => Array ( 
       [id] => 1 
       [from] => Dan9style
       [to] => DaniilErn 
       [text] => Hello! 
     ) 
     [__info:protected] => Array (
        [type] => message 
        [sys.id] => id 
        [sys.orig] => Array ( 
          [id] => 1 
          [from] => Dan9style 
          [to] => DaniilErn 
          [text] => Hello! 
        ) 
        [tainted] => 
        [changed] => 
     )
     [beanHelper:protected] => RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper Object ( )
     [fetchType:protected] => 
     [withSql:protected] => 
     [withParams:protected] => Array ( ) 
     [aliasName:protected] => 
     [via:protected] => 
     [noLoad:protected] =>
     [all:protected] => 
  ) 
)
```

Из БД он вытащил:
id: [1]
from: [Dan9style]
to: [DaniilErn]
text:  [Hello!]

Вроде информации достаточно, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: По идентификатору сортировать нельзя. В данном случае идентификатор сообщения и вовсе не нужен, т.к. операций над одним сообщением не производится.

Comment: А как можно сортировать еще?

Comment: По времени вроде сложно

Comment: Поля timestamp нет в БД?

Comment: Да, по времени получения. Там еще много подводных камней (временная зона, отклонения часов), но в общем случае будет достаточно.